# Pass var Value to another var For Use With body.replaceText

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script

I'm working on a script that takes my Google Forms data and performs a replace function on a predetermined template Doc file using body.replaceText which is working fine. I've copied a truncated version of that below.

I can submit a form and it will replace the values of the template as designed but there are some multiple-choice (Yes or No) questions that are represented by checkboxes on the template Doc.

I've figured out how to Logger.log the checkboxes via unicode but how do I get var systemOperational.getValue = "yes" to assign a value to var systemOperationalYes using IF/Else?

Trying to have "If systemOperational value is Yes then systemOperationalYes = unicode \u2611 Else systemOperationalYes = unicode \u2610".

Pardon me if any of this sounds amateur. This is literally my first go at this.

````
  
  //e.values is an array of form values
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var emailAddress = e.values[1];
  var jobID = e.values[2];
  var storeName = e.values[3];
  var systemOperational = e.values[22];

if (systemOperational.getValue = "yes") {
  var systemOperationalYes = "\u2611";
  Logger.log("\u2611");
} else {
  var systemOperationalYes = "\u2610";
  Logger.log("\u2610");
  }
 
// Locat template file
var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("XXXXXXX").searchFiles('title contains "'+ jobID +'"');
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  Logger.log(file.getId());
}
  //file is the template file, and you get it by ID
  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId());
 
  //We can make a copy of the template, name it, and optionally tell it what folder to live in
  //file.makeCopy will return a Google Drive file object
  var responseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("XXXXXXXXX");
  
  //Converts dateSigned var to MM-dd-yyyy for use in file name
  var convertedDate = new Date(dateSigned);
  Logger.log(convertedDate);
  var formatSignDate = Utilities.formatDate(convertedDate, "GMT-5", "MM-dd-yyyy");
  Logger.log(formatSignDate);

  var folder = responseFolder.createFolder(storeName + '-' + jobID + '-' + formatSignDate);
  var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(storeName + '-' + jobID + '-' + formatSignDate, folder);
 
  //Once we've got the new file created, we need to open it as a document by using its ID
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
 
  //Since everything we need to change is in the body, we need to get that
  var body = doc.getBody();
 
  //Then we call all of our replaceText methods
  body.replaceText('{{SYSOPY}}', systemOperationalYes);
 
  //Lastly we save and close the document to persist our changes
  doc.saveAndClose();
  
  // Convert temporary document to PDF
var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copy.getId()).getAs("application/pdf")
var url = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder.getId()).createFile(pdf);
 
 
// Delete temp file
//DriveApp.getFileById(templateFile.getId()).setTrashed(true);



}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it this way:

```
var timestamp = e.values[0];
var emailAddress = e.values[1];
var jobID = e.values[2];
var storeName = e.values[3];
var systemOperationalYes;

if (e.values[22] = "yes") {
  systemOperationalYes = "\u2611";
  Logger.log("\u2611");
} else {
  systemOperationalYes = "\u2610";
  Logger.log("\u2610");
}
```

Comment: I get TypeError: systemOperational.getValue is not a function
    at autoFillFSTFromForm(Code:48:25)

` if (systemOperational.getValue() == "no") {
  var systemOperationalYes = "\u2611";
  Logger.log(systemOperationalYes);
  } 
  else {
  var systemOperationalYes = "\u2610";
  Logger.log("\u2610");
  }`

I want var systemOperationalYes to display unicode \u2611 when systemOperational.getValue equals 'Yes' and systemOperationalYes to display unicode \u2610 when systemOperational.getValue equals 'No'

Comment: What is e.values[22]?

Comment: Now that I look close I can see that systemOperational is probably not a member of Class Range so that's not going to work.  getValue() is a method of class Range for a spreadsheet.  Your going to have to provide more information about what you are trying to do.

Comment: var systemOperational = e.values[22]; is the column in the Forms sheet that is defining systemOperational. This spits out Yes or No based on the multiple-choice form input. I want to use the answer to that question to define var systemOperationalYes which will then body.replaceText {{SYSOPY}}

Comment: Kinda like if X = Yes then Y = checked-box unicode but if X = No then Y = unchecked-box unicode. Then I replace {{SYSOP}} in my template with the value of Y

Comment: You, sir, are the greatest. That worked.  Thank you so very much.